# GET 404 error when trying to load songs in page

Tags: python, flask

i am developing Music Streaming Platform on Python + Flask framework. At first i had only the main python file, but then i decided to make it in separated files - routes.py, forms.py, models.py and starting of the app function. Before separating it was working fine, but after that i can't load music files. It's says `"GET /uploads/7sq8ul0lyVyvq6jvyAYDS659d.mp3 HTTP/1.1"`, 7sq8ul0lyVyvq6jvyAYDS659d is the name of the song. The strange part is that it's finding all the files in directory, but can't load them.

run.py :

```py
from app import app
from app import db
import logging 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.secret_key='shhhtitssecret'
    app.run(debug=True)
```

routes for the songs in ./app/routes.py

```py
#route for every song
@app.route('/uploads/<filename>')
def uploaded_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)

#route for songs page
@app.route('/songs', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def songs():
    q = request.args.get('q')
    
    if q:
        records = song.query.all()
        songs = []
        
        for s in records:
            name = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(q, s.name)
            artist = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(q, s.artist_name)
            genre = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(q, s.genre)
            
            if name > 60 or artist > 60 or genre > 60:
                if s not in songs: 
                    songs.append(s)

    else:
        songs = song.query.all()
        random.shuffle(songs)
        songs = songs[:20]
 
    return render_template('songs.html', songs = songs)
```

The problem appears in songs.html when i try to loop the songs. I get this for every songs:

```
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/QA7ppkblARwFWhdNQKFP6An30.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/CkCO0jydi5b2Ukzu5EZkjoF4o.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/Z8yW8HwDVgx0KhgIUhQtoibCg.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/JdD9hx53tTLcVQEsIsK23wWKK.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/CRIbJEi4R7gJv0F2x5GPJAFQq.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/pRvwLiT2zwlGcARia5z2SzObn.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/5DmAQCd7OpFs1BdWdGFkGWOn3.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/vYmKpSyTKAYTIHn1NKZv2D3aN.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/NFCkKcWUXJ6IhhPzLbJqWRiQ6.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/UyhmPY8BGhDqZZKQ89QXJASLO.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/7sq8ul0lyVyvq6jvyAYDS659d.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/ErgCAofnyjAK3FD82JqQfFEQz.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/RMzaZbdpFjwE7APqHL76cqO3S.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/kGWzfYbIQM5lyg97RhfGWi6mY.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/JqHGRuJMlQQPLs9zdgCJc8dtE.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/3Il9kce2Jbl7pnyJNQMHaEVqx.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/MSZWvpgVPKhaBCb7RL0Fx8Ayq.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/Na6ET7hwzb1QzCJ3swFn0In4Y.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/QA7ppkblARwFWhdNQKFP6An30.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Comment: Can you specify exactly the problem and what happens?

Comment: @12944qwerty when i open songs.hyml in the web app i get this :
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/QA7ppkblARwFWhdNQKFP6An30.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/CkCO0jydi5b2Ukzu5EZkjoF4o.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/Z8yW8HwDVgx0KhgIUhQtoibCg.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -
INFO:werkzeug:127.0.0.1 - - [21/Apr/2021 21:35:09] "GET /uploads/JdD9hx53tTLcVQEsIsK23wWKK.mp3 HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: Is it possible to provide a screenshot of the webpage? Raw text with no formatting is hard to understand.... (as well as a pasting of the errors in console if any)

Comment: Now that you have divided into separate files, are you doing `import routes` somewhere that the app is going to load?

Comment: Yes, routes is in folder "app"

Comment: Since you're logging, log `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']` in your uploaded function. Also, putting routes in the app folder is not enough, you need to **import** it.

Comment: Could you please run this line and check if files exist: `import pathlib` `pathlib.Path(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)).exists()`

Comment: Also, I think you could serve your files with `Nginx`.

Comment: Yes, they are. The folder is there also.

Comment: What's the value of `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']`? maybe your script can't reach there, what's your operating system? What's the directory of your project? Is the `uploads` folder, is it inside the project directory? sorry for asking these questions, I'm just trying to find your problem.

Comment: I can link the github page of the project : https://github.com/Alexander1022/smotify